# Android listfragment onItemClick not working ?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment, and i want to use onitemclick event. But i have many problems. can  you help me ?   I put event onstart is this right or correct?

Thanks in advance. ..

```
  public class MesajFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
   ...
  @Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), arg2 + " okwww ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it might be a problem somewhere else in your code. I hit the breakpoint I set in the handler method here.. http://pastebin.com/yb12XaTg. I would suspect it has more to do with the way Android handles threading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't calling .show() on your toast message. It should look like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), arg2 + " okwww ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

See the .show() at the end? Your onClick is likely working. It just doesn't appear to be since your Toast message isn't showing

Comment: actually you are right but, i am debugging and a have breakpoints there I put show and it is the same.  so this is not the solution .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. So the toast is showing? What else happens ? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: sorry for mistype. i put breakpoint and it still do not stop on breakpoint.

Comment: If the show is being called and you are getting the Toast message then likely something weird is happening with your project. It means my solution was correct but Eclipse is not allowing the breakpoint to be hit for some reason. If you are using Eclipse, do a full clean on your project (Click Project -> Clean), uninstall your old app, install the newly built version and try to debug that. Make sure in the DDMS view in Eclipse your application's processes has the green debug icon next to it. If it doesn't have that it means you aren't debugging and that's why you aren't hitting the breakpoint

Comment: do not trust to eclipse debugging features if you develop android . thx.

Answer (score 5):

Your example gets the `ListView` and sets its click listener. When extending `ListFragment`, you need to override `onListItemClick` instead:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Handle item click
}
```